# How do I properly remove sensitive data pushed to a Git repo?

Tags: git, github

I pushed a file containing a password to my repo by mistake - FYI the repo is just a small personal project.

Once I realised the password was present I added the file to `.gitignore` and executed `git rm -r --cached <filename>`, committed and pushed to the repo.

I now realise the password is still present in the history - **what is the best way to remove it?**

I read the [Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) page on Github which suggests changing the password - which I have done - but I would like to remove the history as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: How many commits have already gone on top of the password commit in your remote?

Comment: I have 5 commits after the one containing the password

Comment: And one more question: is there anything else which went into the password commit other than the password file itself?

Comment: Yes, in that commit other things were added too, thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since you have already made 5 commits since the commit containing the clear text password, you best bet is to do a `git rebase -i` in interactive mode on your local branch.  Find the SHA-1 of the commit where you added the clear text password, and type the following:

```
git rebase --interactive dba507c^
```

where `dba507c` are the first 7 characters of the SHA-1 for the bad commit.

Change this:

```
pick dba507c comment for commit containing clear text password
```

To this:

```
edit dba507c I have removed the clear text password
```

Make the change to the password file to remove the clear text, then commit your result like this:

```
git commit --all --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

Finish the rebase, then push your (correct) local branch to the remote via:

```
git push -f origin your_branch
```

You will need to force push `your_branch` because you have rewritten history (by modifying the password file).  Now you have all your latest commits, but you have removed the clear text.

Comment: For future reference, if you had caught the clear text commit before making any others in your remote, you could have fixed it with a one-line solution.

Comment: If you are trying to change something in your first commit start off with `git rebase [-i] --root $tip` instead

Comment: This answer, as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872700/8075923) are both of great value for the community. Thanks guys, +1.

Answer (score 19):

If it was the previous commmit, then remove the password from the file and run

```
git add file_with_pwd
git commit --amend 
git push -f origin master
```

Note: Once you posted that here on Stackoverflow, many guys may have already cloned the repo (you have the same username on github and just one repository). **Change the password!**

Comment: Upvote for picking up that security hole (I have not cloned that repo FYI).

Comment: I did, but I will **not** harm the OP in any case. I did it just to show him that he needs to change the password, since other guys probably won't tell him that.

Comment: `page on Github which suggests changing the password - which I have done` - May be useful to future readers, not the OP.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post **I have** changed the password. FYI it isn't the previous commit

Comment: @NRKirby Perfect! I have overlooked that. Will keep the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset --soft` in your branch to undo that last commit.
Then remove the creds from the respective files.
And do the command sequence `git add <updated-file>`, `git commit`, and `git push -f`.
E.g:

```bash
git checkout <branch-name>
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git add <updated-file>
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -f origin <branch-name>
```